# What happens on a first login?

Tags: 11.10, unity, installation, login

Just asking. I haven't freshly installed Ubuntu for a while now, and I am just curious. If one were to install, say 11.10 on a computer, would any program open up on the first login? like a welcome to ubuntu banner or a guide to ubuntu from the help section?

Comment: nothing of that sort happens in my experience (11.10 64 bit) all u get is login screen and then ur desktop :)

Comment: I don't think this is a real question, tbh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no welcome screen, Ubuntu banner, or a guide to Ubuntu from the help section. Mint 12 however, does.

Comment: One could argue that Ubuntu doesn't need a "Guide" - it's pretty easy to use anyway. ;)

Comment: @jrg That is definitely true! Ubuntu doesn't need one.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. As you are reading this, I am typing up a launchpad bug report for the need of one. New users won't know how to do much on a clean install of Ubuntu, unless they are told how to do it by a friend or see how to on a youtube walkthrough. The Ubuntu community needs to make one that comes up on default, and hopefully, that can be included on 12.04

Comment: @user25757 That's the other side of the argument. :D I was thinking of something that is not necessarily a welcome screen, but something like a notification that pops up at first login that, upon being clicked, leads to a tutorial that explains the basics of Ubuntu.

Comment: If you want to help show the importance of it, go to the link at the bottom. Click on launchpad where it says "Does this affect you" and hit yes. Then tell other people to do it. That way the need for a guide will be explained!!! https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/900985